# What happens when you have a case statement with no argument and the when clauses are lambdas?

Tags: ruby

This code does not perform as I expect:

```
case    
when -> { false } then "why?"        
else "This is what I expect"        
end      
# => "why?"
```

Neither does this

```
case
when ->(x) {false} then "why?"  
else "This is what I expect"
end  
# => "why?"
```

The first `then` clause is executed in both cases, which must mean that the lambda I supply to the `when` clause is not being called.  I understand that the case equality operator `===` should be called on whatever the subject of the `when` clause is.  I am wondering what goes on the other side of the `===` when there is no argument supplied to `case`.  I was thinking it might be `nil`, but it can't be:

```
-> {false} === nil
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

->(x) {false} === nil
# => false
```

This performs as expected and, if it were being executed, would lead to my expected `case` results or an exception.  Can someone explain the results above?  It seems that the case equality operator isn't being used at all, and yet the first `when` clause is evaluating to `true`.  BTW, I am doing this because the output of a `case` can be used for variable assignment and it is less wordy then having several `elsif` clauses.  I would like to be able to use arbitrary `Proc`s in a case statement with no argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
case    
when -> { false } then puts "why?"        
else puts "This is what I expect"        
end

case    
when 'cat' then puts "why?"        
else puts "This is what I expect"        
end

case    
when -> { false }.call then puts "why?"        
else puts "This is what I expect"        
end
```

outputs:

```
why?
why?
This is what I expect
```

As The Pickaxe ( http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9 ) says, there are two forms of case statement.

> The first allows a series of conditions to be evaluated, executing
>   code corresponding to the first condition that is true: case when ‹
>   boolean-expression ›+ ‹ then › ...
>
> The second form of a case expression takes a target expression
>   following the case keyword. case target when ‹ comparison ›+ ‹ then ›
>   ...

In your case (`case` without target) any expression that is not `false` or `nil` (such as a Proc or the string 'cat') evaluates to true. The Proc is not executed, unless you `call` it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `case` statement without a parameter to act similar to an `if` statement. For example:

```
case
when x > 0 then puts "positive"
else puts "negative"
end
```

You're assuming that it's trying to compare to `nil`, which isn't the case. Rather, when there's no parameter, the `case` statement is only testing for a "truthy" value (anything except `nil` and `false`). So when it hits your first `when` statement, it's checking to see if your `Proc` (meaning the actual ruby `Proc` object, **not** the results of executing your `Proc`) is `nil` or `false`, which isn't. Since it's "truthy", that code gets executed.

Try this, and you'll notice the `Proc` never even gets called/executed (you'll only see `"bar"`, not `"foo"`):

```
case
when -> { puts 'foo' } then puts 'bar'
else puts "This line will never be printed"
end
```

Comment: Thansk for explaining this